# Where in Faerun can a character receive medical training?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, forgotten-realms, lore

I'm making a DnD 5e character who specializes in the Medicine skill and has the Healer feat. Canonically, what institute of learning in Faerûn could provide the character with this training? Im looking more for an academic location verse a clerical or religious one.

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that due to the prevalence of magical healing in Faerun, and its intrinsic tie to the gods.....most places of healing are temples, not schools. You have your Clerics for the 'heavy' healing, and your physicians for the long-term care or treatment of those who can't afford magical healing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Almost any Temple

Healing from clerics is common in Faerun, so most places of healing would be temples rather than schools. There are too many temples/churches to list, but some ideas may include:

- [Candlekeep](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Candlekeep)
- [Elturel](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Elturel) (especially High Harvest Home - temple to [Chauntea](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Chauntea))
- Any temple of [Ilmater](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Ilmater) (especially [House of the Broken God](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_the_Broken_God) in Calimshan)